# write to a JSON folder from the following element

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js, fs

I want to know how to read/write from/to `json` files.

```js
const Discord = require ('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const {prefix, token,} = require('./config.json');
const fs = require ('fs');

    client.login(token)

        client.on('message', message => {
        if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "TC")) { //TC = team create

                var args = message.content.split(' ').join(' ').slice(4);
                if(!args) return message.channel.send("No")

                var TeamCreate = `{"NameTeam": "${args}", "ManagerTeam": ${message.author.id}}`

            fs.writeFile("./team.json", TeamCreate, (x) => {
                if (x) console.error(x)
              })}});
```

The `json` file will display :
`{"NameTeam": "teste","ManagerTeam": 481117441955463169}`

And I would like that each time we place the order, it gets added to the `json` file.

Example:

```
1 first order = {"NameTeam": "teste","ManagerTeam": 481117441955463169}
2 second order = {"NameTeam": "teste","ManagerTeam": 481117441955463169}, {"NameTeam": "teste2","ManagerTeam": 1234567890}
```

Comment: What is a *json folder*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to make a `json` file that contains a list of teams.

The easy way to do that is to read and parse the json, make changes to it, and then stringify the jsonand update the file. Also, making json with strings is really messy and can lead to syntax errors, while in javascript turning js objects into json is as simple as doing `JSON.stringify(javascriptObject)`

Try something like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token, } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');

client.login(token)

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "TC")) { //TC = team create

        var args = message.content.split(' ').join(' ').slice(4);
        if (!args) return message.channel.send("No")

        var team = {
            NameTeam: args,
            ManagerTeam: message.author.id
        }

        fs.readFile("./team.json", (err, data) => {
            if (!err && data) {
                var parsedJson;
                try {
                    parsedJson = JSON.parse(data);
                    //Make sure the parsedJson is an array
                    if (!(parsedJson instanceof Array)) {
                        parsedJson = [];
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log("Couldn't parse json.");
                    parsedJson = [];
                }
                finally {
                    //Add the newly created team to parsedJson
                    parsedJson.push(team);

                    //Write file, stringifying the json.
                    fs.writeFile("./team.json", JSON.stringify(parsedJson), (err) => {
                        if (!err) {
                            console.log("Successfully created team.");
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Error writing to file.")
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error reading json");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Your help is really precious to me.